# Java HTTPS Connection fails with JAVA 1.8.0_241 on AIX

Tags: java, https, socketfactory

I have a nice class that connects with https and a nice certificate to my Server.
Everythink works like a charm with the version 1.8.0_231.

When I update java to 1.8.0_241 it looks like the certificate isn't attached anymore.

I doing some searches but it seams the update is to new.

Anyone else with same problems?

Comment: try whether this helps you 
http://emo.sourceforge.net/cert-login-howto.html

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But I think everything is set up in a proper manner.

Comment: Please post the exact error message. In case it is a public server it would be good also to post the server url. Alternatively you can test the server yourself for TLS related problems: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

Comment: The server is not acessable from the internet. With a little bit luck I get tomorrow a role back to the old Java version. So I can see if the Java version is realy the problem.

Comment: And when I use postman to make the request with the same certificate everything works fine too

Comment: After the role back everything works again. So if you have some unexpected errors with https connections check if you use Java 1.8.0_241

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use Java_8.jre.8.0.0.605.I.
Without changing the code 600 and 608 works.

Comment: In the log files I have I didn't get any error messages. But it seems that setSSLSocketFactory() from httpsURLConnection didn't work in a proper way.